# Phalcon php - Multiples joins

Tags: php, phalcon

When I try to add more than one inner join in my query I have the following error:

Scanning error before '] JOIN [] JOIN [...' when parsing

Here's my code:

```
$query = myModelHere::query()
    ->innerJoin("Model1")
    ->innerJoin("Model2")
    ->limit(10)
    ->execute();
```

Someone had that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug and was solved in 1.3.2 version

See:
https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/pull/2220

Answer (score 0):

You can try use [PHQL](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html)

Anyway, report on [GitHub](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues)...probably it's a bug